# Include a self-contained asset bundle with Broccoli / ember-cli

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

I am using [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/), self-compiled: not via bower, but directly generated and downloaded from the jquery-ui website. I have put it into `myapp/vendor/bundles/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom`

In my `Brocfile` I am loading the CSS and JS resources:

```
app.import('vendor/bundles/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.css');
app.import('vendor/bundles/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css');
app.import('vendor/bundles/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.js');
```

The CSS is then included in the `vendor.css` resource, and the js in the `vendor.js` resource.

But this is not providing the full jquery-ui component. In particular, the file `jquery-ui.css` is using this rule:

```
.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #72b42d;
    background: #285c00 url("images/ui-bg_inset-soft_10_285c00_1x100.png") 50% bottom repeat-x;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Which is addressing the image in `vendor/bundles/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/images/ui-bg_inset-soft_10_285c00_1x100.png`. That file is not available in the `dist` folder.

The `url("images/...")` is *relative* to the path of the CSS itself. This is the structure of the `jquery-ui` component:

```
vendor/bundles/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/
├── external
│   └── jquery
│       └── jquery.js
├── images
│   ├── ui-bg_diagonals-small_0_aaaaaa_40x40.png
│   ├── ui-bg_diagonals-thick_15_444444_40x40.png
│   ├── ui-bg_diagonals-thick_95_ffdc2e_40x40.png
│   ├── ui-bg_glass_55_fbf5d0_1x400.png
│   ├── ui-bg_highlight-hard_30_285c00_1x100.png
│   ├── ui-bg_highlight-soft_33_3a8104_1x100.png
│   ├── ui-bg_highlight-soft_50_4eb305_1x100.png
│   ├── ui-bg_highlight-soft_60_4ca20b_1x100.png
│   ├── ui-bg_inset-soft_10_285c00_1x100.png
│   ├── ui-icons_4eb305_256x240.png
│   ├── ui-icons_72b42d_256x240.png
│   ├── ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png
│   └── ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png
├── index.html
├── jquery-ui.css
├── jquery-ui.js
├── jquery-ui.min.css
├── jquery-ui.min.js
├── jquery-ui.structure.css
├── jquery-ui.structure.min.css
├── jquery-ui.theme.css
└── jquery-ui.theme.min.css
```

What I would like to make available for my application is:

- jquery-ui.css
- jquery-ui.js
- jquery-ui.theme.css
- images/ directory

How can this be solved in Broccoli?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved (hacked?) my problem, so I will post a reference here for others. If somebody can comment on the chosen solution, I am more than happy to receive comments:

I have used a similar method to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23872893/647991)

First, install some broccoli tools:

```
npm install --save-dev broccoli-static-compiler
npm install --save-dev broccoli-merge-trees
```

Now modify your `Brocfile.js`:

```
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
var pickFiles  = require('broccoli-static-compiler');

var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

...

// We provide bundles tree as-is
var bundlesTree = pickFiles('vendor/bundles', {
   srcDir: '/',
   files: ['*'],
   destDir: '/assets/bundles',
});

module.exports = mergeTrees([app.toTree(), bundlesTree]);
```

(Do not `app.import` the bundles anymore)

Now the bundles are available at `dist/assets/bundles`, so you can load CSS and JS in the `index.html` manually:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bundles/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bundles/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css">

...

<script src="assets/bundles/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Since the CSS is loaded directly from the `html`, relative references to the images are working fine, and grabbing  the correct files in `assets/bundles/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/images/...`.

This works but is a bit hacky: it requires to manually import assets on the `html` file.

Does anybody know of an alternative which only involves the `Brocfile`? Can broccoli actually re-allocate imports so that relative references work transparently? How?

Comment: Hi @jeckyll2hide, thank you for sharing the idea. I am running into the same thing and looking for answer to best migrate to ember cli. I have one quick question about reference from ```jquery-ui.min.css```. After using the brocolli-static-compiler, do you need to correct all the jquery-ui css reference from ```images/...``` to ```assets/bundles/images/...``` in order to make the reference work? I am afraid then it will make jquery-ui less portable because every time if I start from scratch I need to manually change the reference and it also be hard to upgrade jquery-ui in the future?

Comment: But I also see other people using the same technic as in including [polymer into ember cli project](http://www.programwitherik.com/how-to-add-polymer-to-your-ember-project/). So I guess that's the only way to migrate the problem for the moment? Thank!